# subimport including wrong file

Tags: input, import

I am trying to learn the *import* package but I find it extremely unreliable - perhaps I am missing something? One case study I tried is as follows:

Created 3 tex files:

- ./main.tex
- ./bla.tex
- ./X/bla.tex

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
\subimport{X/}{bla.tex}
\end{document}
```

bla.tex

```
BLA
```

X/bla.tex

```
XBLA
```

However, when compiled, in the produced pdf I see `BLA` instead of `XBLA` as I have expected. Only when I remove the file ./bla.tex (or change its name), the correct one X/bla.tex is included and `XBLA` appears in the pdf.

What is going on? How can I make it work?

In my real-life case scenario with much bigger file structure, I have some common file names in each directory, such as `config.tex` and cannot afford making each name unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refering to [manual](ftp://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf):

> Depending on on how your TeX ystem is configured, if a file with the
>   same name as the import file exists in the current directory or in the
>   `TEXINPUTS` path, that other file will be read in preference to one in
>   the import directory.

So, it tries to read the file from the `.` dir (for you MWE), finds it and includes, so, the result is "BLA".

The solution is to use the starred version: [`\subimport*{X/}{bla.tex}`](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/51ecf8e8335f3d63700d672a).